# Submitting the data based on the radio select in django

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I am trying to display some values in html template using for loop.
I need to edit the selected record based on the radio select and I am not sure how to send the selected record to views.py when submitting the form.

Here I am displaying the open tickets, and a radio button at the end. The user needs to edit a record by selecting the radio button and submitting the form.

**opencalls.html**

```
    <form method="post" action="" id="opencallsupdate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2>Open Calls</h2>
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Call raised date</th>
        <th>Attended Engineer</th>
        <th>Problem type</th>
        <th>Call Status</th>
        <th>remarks</th>
        <th>Expected Closing Date</th>
        <th>TAT</th>
        <th>Select to close</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for i in obj1 %}
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> {{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td value="{{ i.customer_name }}" name="customer_name">{{ i.customer_name }}</td>
        <td value="{{ i.created_date }}">{{ i.created_date }}</td>
        <td value="{{ i.assigned_engineer }}">{{ i.assigned_engineer }}</td>
        <td value="{{ i.problem_type }}">{{ i.problem_type }}</td>
        <td value="{{ i.status }}">{{ i.status }}</td>
        <td value="{{ i.remarks }}">{{ i.remarks }}</td>
        <td value="{{ i.exp_closing_time }}">{{ i.exp_closing_time }}</td>
        <td value="{{ i.tat }}">{{ i.tat }}</td>
        <td><label><input type="radio" name="optradio"></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default " value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my views.py in which I am sending the open ticket details to be displayed.

**views.py**

```
def open_calls(request):
    obj = Call.objects.all()
    obj1 = obj.filter(status='open')
    if (request.POST):
        data = request.POST.get("customer_name")
        data1 = request.POST.get("optradio")
        print (data)

    context = {'obj1':obj1}
    return render(request, 'opencalls.html',context)
```

I am not able to get the details since it is in a for loop.

Comment: You will generate a multiple radio with the same name. If you want your code to run you must define your from in the table with multiple submit (One submit for each line of the table)

Comment: I tried but not working, anyway i made it work by sending the unique id of the records to another page and updated it in database. and i removed the radio select option.